# Bootstrap div in div with different sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have (in bootstrap) div in div. The div in "bottom" is a background (gradient, and smaller height than foreground DIV) and in foreground is an image + tekst. [div in div with image and gradien behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIOeK.jpg)

The LOGO is an image, SOME TEXT will be in same div with LOGO, and the gradient DIV is behind...
I hope You undertand what I mean... Thnks in advanced

```css
.container-color-nospace {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.preporucujemo {
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 12%, #27aae2 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 12%,#27aae2 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ffffff 12%,#27aae2 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#27aae2',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<section class="container container-color-nospace">
  <article class="preporucujemo">
   <article>
    <img src="img/logo_plavi.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="logo"> SOME TEXT
   </article>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Understood the content . But what's your question ?

Comment: <section class="container">
 <article class="gradient-background">
  <article class="image-container">
  <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="some"> SOME TEXT
  </article>
 </article>

</section> How can i do like on image...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a CodePen, JS Fiddle or Bootply to help see what you are attempting to do.